# Is it possible to directly communicate with another user?

Tags: support

I would like to chat with another user, is this possible? I tried searching help and the FAQs and looked for a link on the profiles page and came up empty, but I have no doubt that I could have easily missed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Stack Exchange has a chat system.

You can find the general room for [Home Improvement](https://diy.stackexchange.com) at https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111/home-improvement. There are also post-specific rooms created from time to time under certain circumstances (like when there's a lot of back-and-forth between two users) but none are active at the moment.

To chat with another user, address them in a comment and ask them to join you in the chat room linked above. Remember that the site has a global audience, so they might not be active at the same time you are and unable to respond immediately. Remember also that they might not want to chat with you; **respect their wishes and don't hound them**.

Comment: Ok, I hear that there is a common room at the link provided, which I checked out, and a side room where a non-public, but not private, conversations can be held.